# GCD going back to main thread

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, nsxmlparser, grand-central-dispatch

In my application I load information from several (6-10) websites using NSXMLParser and then load the information into views.

Right now, my applications is set up so that it loops through the sites in `viewDidLoad` in my main view controller and loads them each in a background thread that I created. It does this in a background thread so that the user does not have to wait for all of the sites to load before the view loads.

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *dict in self.sitesArray) {
    SiteData *data = [[SiteData alloc] init];
    [data setDelegate:self];
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^(void) {
        [data loadSite:[dict objectForKey:@"SiteName"]];
    });

}
```

In SiteData, I load the site using NSXMLParser (all of the delegate methods also implemented properly)

```
-(void)loadSite:(NSString *)site{
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[self fullURLForSiteName:site]];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];
    return;
}
```

When the NSXMLParser has finished the document and the SiteData instance is populated with the site's data, it passes itself to a method in my main view controller on the main thread.

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{    
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
         [delegate successfullyLoadedSite:self];
    });
}
```

`successfullyLoadedSite:` loads the passed site's data into a view and displays it to the user. Note that multiple site's data are displayed on the same screen.

**What I want to happen:** I want each site's data to appear on the screen as it is loaded, not having to wait until all of them finish loading for the view to refresh.

**What is happening:** One of the sites loads and displays, then I have to wait for all of the rest to load, then all the rest get displayed at once.

From console logging it seems that once it calls `successfullyLoadedSite:` on the main queue the first time, everything gets run on the main queue. Once the first `successfullyLoadedSite:` on the main queue gets called, it loads all of the sites into objects, then loads them into views.

Any ideas what's going on? If you can't tell I'm new to multithreading. Thanks :)

---

**Edit:**
I create `backgroundQueue` like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue;
```

and in `init`

```
backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("uni.que.identifier.bgqueue", NULL);
```

and release it in `dealloc` with:

```
dispatch_release(backgroundQueue);
```

Comment: Do you mean that `loadSite:` is executed on a background thread the first time and then always on the main thread? Is `backgroundQueue` a serial queue? Can you show how you create it? Do you ever destroy it?

Comment: @Costique I appended that information to my question. Sorry, I don't know if it is a serial queue or not but I'm sure you can tell.

I'm almost sure that `loadSite:` is executed on a background thread the first time and then always on the main thread but I'm not positive. Is there a way I can check? Thanks.

Comment: So the dispatch queue is not serial. Put `NSLog(@"%s", [NSThread isMainThread] ? "main thread" : "background thread");` in `loadSite:` to make sure it gets executed in background as it should. When do you release the dispatch queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The queue of using dispatch_queue_create function to create is serial queue,
then dispatch_queue_create submitted block will execute as sequential order.

use:

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue =
    dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
```

Comment: Your suggestion seems like it is working... all of the things done on the main thread get called at the same time but i think it is just because all of the sites finish loading around the same time. thanks!!